# Creating two possible polynomial functions with specific criteria.

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

I need to find two possible polynomial function, but each one must have a different degree, and they both must have these features:

- Leading Coefficient is $-2$;
- Zeros are at $-3, -1, 4$.

I know the zeros would mean that somewhere in the equation there is:
$(x+3)$, $(x+1)$, and $(x-4)$. I also know $a=-2$. I just don't know how to put it all together to find the actual functions.

UPDATE I FOUND ONE: $-2X^3+26X+24$

Comment: Do you mean $-3$, $-1$ and $4$ are all the zeros (or all the real zeros), or is it allowed to have zeros other than those?

Comment: The zeros are at -3,-1 and 4.

Comment: @RobertIsrael ^ Hope that clarify things

Comment: Understood, but you won't find a polynomial of degree three that satisfies all those requirements, and a polynomial of higher degree has more roots--possibly complex or with multiplicity greater than 1.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi The teacher just sent an email saying the first criteria is not needed anymore so it's just the Leading Coefficient is −2 and Zeros are at −3,−1,4 that are important. How would I go about doing this.

Comment: In general, you let your polynomial be $a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$.  As you noted, $a_0=5$. When you fix the value of the polynomial to $0$ for one of the roots, you get a linear equation in the $a_i$ coefficients.  You have three equations, and with $a_3 = -2$, there were only two unknowns.  But when you drop the constraint on $a_3$, you have three equations in three unknowns.  You repeat the process for a fourth-degree polynomial, and that's where Robert Israel's question becomes important.  If you have no constraints on the fourth root, you can fix, say, $a_4=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $-3$, $-1$ and $4$ are all the zeros (including complex zeros), then by the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) your polynomial must be of the form $f(x) = -2 (x+3)^i (x+1)^j (x-4)^k$ for some positive integers $i,j,k$.  That would have $f(0) = -2 \cdot 3^i \cdot (-4)^k$, so it's good you don't need a restriction on $f(0)$.

If you mean $-3$, $-1$ and $4$ are all the **real** zeros, then you could have
$f(x) = -2 (x+3)^i (x+1)^j (x-4)^k g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial with no real zeros.  For example, you could take $g(x) = x^2 + r$ where $r > 0$.  With $i=j=k=1$ you could take $r = 5/24$ to get $f(0)=5$.  Or try   $g(x)=x^4+5/24$ to get a polynomial of different degree.

Comment: I found one: $f(x)=-2x^3=26x+24$

Comment: You mean $-2x^3+26x+24$.  Yes, that's $-2(x+3)(x+1)(x-4)$.

Comment: Oops! Yes that is what I mean't i'm not sure how to find another one.

Comment: What about $-2 (x+3)^2 (x+1)(x-4)$?